# Firebase doesn't insert data - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Okay, I'm new to Android so any help would be very welcome and appreciated. I'm trying to insert a string which will be a child of a User id in firebase, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                FirebaseUser mUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String uId=mUser.getUid();


                DatabaseReference rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                DatabaseReference Ref = rootReference.child(uId).push();
                Ref.setValue(diet);
```

The code executes without errors, however, when I open Firebase the data is missing.
I changed the rules in Firebase but it didn't help.

Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
```

}

Comment: Check if your Firebase is set up correctly in Android Studio. I would also suggest checking Logcat for possible runtime errors, that aren't reflected while building the app.

Comment: Firebase doesn't store null values, possibly uId is null. Please log it.

Comment: Have you tried to attach a complete listener to the setValue operation?